# Linking Service Hops with Zipkin and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, trace, distributed-system, zipkin

I am trying to link three HTTP service hops in NodeJS together into a single Zipkin trace.  I have three services

```
service-main
service-hello
service-goodbye
```

The service `service-main` calls `service-hello`, and `service-hello` needs to call `service-goodbye` to complete.  Zipkin can see these calls, but links them together as two separate traces. (`service-main` calling `service-hello`, and `service-hello` calling `service-goodbye`.

The services are implemented in `express`, and the fetching happens via `node-fetch`.

I create an instrumented service fetcher with code that looks like this

```
const createFetcher = (remoteServiceName, tracer) => {
  const wrapFetch = require('zipkin-instrumentation-fetch');
  return wrapFetch(fetch,
    {
      tracer:tracer,
      remoteServiceName:remoteServiceName
    }
  );
}
```

and I instrument express with code that looks like this

```
app.use(zipkinMiddleware({tracer}));
```

and finally, I create my tracer with code that looks like this

```
const createTracer = (localServiceName) => {
  const tracer = new Tracer({
    ctxImpl: new CLSContext('zipkin'),
    recorder: new BatchRecorder({
      logger: new HttpLogger({
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans',
        jsonEncoder: JSON_V2
      })
    }),
    localServiceName: localServiceName // name of this application
  });
  return tracer;
}
```

You can see the above code in context in [the following github repository](https://github.com/astorm/zipkin-example).

I've done all this by cargo-culting the code samples from the zipkin github repositories, and I don't know enough about zipkin's implementation to diagnose this further.

How to I get zipkin to see the `service-main` -> `service-hello` -> `service-goodbye` call chain as a single trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up not being on Zipkin's end, but instead in how I was instrumenting the express server.

```
app.get('/main', async function (req, res) {
    //...
})

app.use(zipkinMiddleware({tracer}));
```

I had added the zipkin middleware *after* my call to `app.get`.  Express executes middlwares in order and makes no distinction between middleware for a named route vs. something added via `app.use`.

Doing things like this

```
app.use(zipkinMiddleware({tracer}));

app.get('/main', async function (req, res) {
    //...
})
```

Gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is related to https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-js/pull/498, could you try with zipkin-context-cls@0.19.2-alpha.7 and change `ctxImpl` into `ctxImpl = new CLSContext('zipkin', true);`?

Comment: thank you for you time/attention -- +1.  I made the suggested changes and zipkin still sees two traces instead of a single trace.  Branch is here: https://github.com/astorm/zipkin-example/tree/stackoverflow/61800994 -- Bonuse Question if you have the time/know -- what job do these context objects do?  Are they where the logic foo passing on the trace id exists?